# Error SQL Server 2008 NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Tengo varios servidores SQL Server 2008 instalados en varias maquinas que realizan todas las noches unos procesos de sincronizacin de informacion. Todos funcionan correctamente salvo uno que se ha instalado recientemente en el que obtengo el siguiente error:

**Error de INSERT porque las siguientes opciones SET tienen una configuración incorrecta: 'NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT'. Compruebe que las opciones SET son correctas y se pueden usar con vistas indizadas y/o índices en columnas calculadas y/o índices filtrados y/o notificaciones de consulta y/o métodos de tipo de datos XML y/u operaciones de índice espacial.**

También he observado que en otro proceso obtenía un error de desbordamiento aritmético lanzando una consulta que lanzo también en todos los servidores. El error lo daba al hacer un AVG de un valor. Pero como comento solo en este servidor.

Pensaba que se debería a la configuración del servidor pero he revisado las configuraciones en varios servidores y están igual. Ya no se si reviso lo que ocasiona el error. Adjunto dos capturas.

[image: Configuración 01]
[image: Configuración 02]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finalmente no era problema del Servidor y si de la configuración de la base de datos.

[image: Configuración correcta]

Estos tres valores estaban a True y ocasionaban el error.